# How do you test single-touch activities on the android sdk emulator?

Tags: android-emulator

This may seem straightforward but for some reason my emulator won't simulate any of the MotionEvent events taken from [this](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Game/beginning-android-games/com/badlogic/androidgames/SingleTouchTest.java.htm) example. I can use the mouse arrow to click on any button in the emulator but I can't see how I can emulate touching the screen.

I know the emulator does not support multi-touch but what about single-touch? I checked the manifest file and the "min SDK version" is 3 and the "target SDK version" is 9. No exceptions are displayed in the console window. Do I need to enable it somehow?

Comment: I'll just provide the answer before someout points out my stupidity - I forgot to set the the text from the StringBuilder on the TextView. Had I checked the LogCat window I would see all the events being logged as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A perfect example of how not to do it - answer is in the comments